# Find intersections between mesh and curve inside it

Tags: finite-element, mesh, deal.ii, mesh-traversal

I have a simple square mesh, and a curve (discretised by another mesh) inside it. Here a picture worths thousand words. What I want to achieve is to find, for every cell $K$ of the circular (discretised) grid, I want to get the intersection points with the cells T of other grid. Here they are marked with a red dot.

[image]

**What is the correct algorithmic to follow?** Of course, if two consecutive support points for the circular grid are in different cells, then I can compute the intersection, but in general it may be that a cell $T$ is cut and no support points of the other mesh are in there, see again the picture above.

I started with FEnics, but I think in this case deal.II is the way to go. So, any explanation in the deal.II "lingo" is more than welcome.

Comment: Is it possible that one edge of your curve crosses multiple edges of the background mesh?

Comment: @DanielShapero yes, that is possible, and it is indeed what happens in the top right cell!

Comment: Ah of course, I should have looked more carefully! In any case, if you're using deal.II I think a good place to start would be to find the cell containing an initial point of the curve and work by breadth-first search from there. The functions you'll want are probably [compute_point_locations](https://dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/namespaceGridTools.html#a8e8bb9211264d2106758ac4d7184117e) and [get_neighbors](https://dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/classCellAccessor.html#a87e47f00c82296ea941b41c0e0201f47).

Comment: When I had to deal with non-conforming meshes, I used [Clipper](http://angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) to determine the cut areas needed for the domain integrals. Until now, I couldn't find software that can clip arbitrary polyhedra, so going to 3D could be difficult.

Comment: @DanielShapero I started with those functions indeed, but I don't know what you mean with "breadth-first search" in this case.

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti I'm not planning to go to 3D, I am completely fine with 2D. So, is Clipper able to return also the intersection points?

Comment: @bobinthebox What he means is that if you have one cell that is intersected, you next consider its neighbors, then their neighbors, etc.

Comment: in MATLAB, the short piece of code [curve-intersections](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22441-curve-intersections) could compute intersection points of two curves.

Comment: Have a look at the marching-cubes algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes

Comment: @bobinthebox I don't know. I performed two steps: 1) To compute the interface integrals, I intersected the edges of the mesh with the curve (which was assumed to consist of straight segments). I only intersected those mesh edges that were within the bounding box of the curve to save time.

Comment: @bobinthebox 2) To compute the domain integrals, it would have been difficult to reconstruct the cut area based on the intersection points. First, one cannot simply take the convex hull of the intersection points when the cut area is a non-convex polygon. Second, there is no intersection point when the curve lies completely within a cell. Therefore, I used polygon-polygon intersection based on a library.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers and comments have good suggestions already. In practice, you will probably find that on coarse meshes most cells have no intersection with the curve and, assuming that your curve is contained in a relatively small part of the domain, you can easily exclude the case that a cell is intersected  by the curve using bounding boxes. To this end, you split the curve into a moderate number of bounding boxes each of which covers one line segment either in its entirety, or a smaller piece of a line segment, and intersect them with the bounding box of a cell. If the intersection is empty, you know the curve doesn't go through the cell.

Comparing lots of bounding boxes of cells against lots of bounding boxes of line segments is expensive. You can make this much more efficient if you use an rtree of bounding boxes. deal.II has classes both for bounding boxes and for rtrees.

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangBangerth. I understood the idea, and I like it a lot as indeed I'd be using deal.II capabilities to the full. What I am missing is *how* to compute those coordinates. From your answer, it seems that I only can say which cells are intersected. But that could've been achieved also by `calling compute_point_locations()`
 repeatedly.

Comment: @bobinthebox I don't know about the details of how deal.II library works, but generally the process for using spatial data structures such as rtrees is you use the rtree to filter the number of elements you need to perform a complex intersection check on. So you would first find what cells are intersected, then manually (or using another library call if present) to check if your curve intersects any elements which are in the filtered cells.

Comment: @bobinthebox `compute_point_locations()` is expensive on its own. You want to make sure that you only look at cells for which there is a reasonable chance that a point is inside. That's why `GridTools::Cache` exists.

Answer (score 1):

When I faced this problem in the past, in the context of domain decomposition across mismatched surface tessellations, I ended up basically using the Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm (polygon-to-polygon clipping) to clip every polygon against every other, combined with a broad-phase culling based on BVH/BSH over the interface elements. It can definitely be applied to this problem, though it is possibly overkill if you only want intersection points (and don't care about topology/polygonization of those points). One of the tricky bits with this is that the resulting clipped region can basically be an arbitrary polygon, so you might find that you need further algorithmic machinery (ie triangulation/meshing) in order to do any FE-like things with the result (like interpolation/resampling/bases).

[Sutherland-Hodgman Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm)